# Daubechies wavelet transform

Tags: discrete-signals, signal-analysis, wavelet, transform, signal-synthesis

i have N samples obtained by sampling a signal with lot of frequency contents. How will i apply daubechies wavelet transform to obtain the frequency and its location? i need to write a program which will process the signal and gives the frequency and location as the result.

Comment: If you have multiple frequencies (more like bursts of frequency?) in the signal, which one are you  interested of?

Comment: i am interested in getting the higher frequencies(i.e above a threshold which i set) present.

Comment: Higher as in higher frequency or higher amplitude?

Comment: if possible i would like to know the amplitude of the signal at those higher frequencies as well.

Comment: Have you managed to do the transform already?

Comment: No, i have not yet done the code as i am finding it difficult to understand the entire concept itself. Kindly provide an answer for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you need a general explanation of the discrete wavelet transform (DWT). DWT breaks a signal down into subbands distributed evenly in a logarithmic frequency scale, each subband sampled at a rate proportional to the frequencies in that band. The traditional Fourier transformation has no time domain resolution at all, or when done using many short windows on a longer data, equal resolution at all frequencies. The distribution of samples in the time and frequency domain by DWT is of form:

```
log f
 |XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX  X = a sample
 |X X X X X X X X   f = frequency
 |X   X   X   X     t = time
 |X       X
 |X
 |X                
  ----------------t
```

Single subband decomposition and reconstruction:

```
    -> high -> decimate -------------> dilute -> high
   |   pass    by 2      high subband  by 2      pass \
in |                                                   + out
   |                                                  /  =in
    -> low  -> decimate -------------> dilute -> low
       pass    by 2      low subband   by 2      pass
```

This creates two subbands from the input signal, both sampled at half
the original frequency. The filters approximate halfband finite impulse response (FIR) filters
and are determined by the choice of wavelet. Using Daubechies wavelets
(and most others), the data can be reconstructed to the exact original
even when the halfband filters are not perfect. Note that in the above scheme, the total amount of information (samples) stays the same throughout.

```
Decimation by 2: ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQR -> ACEGIKMOQ
  Dilution by 2: ACEGIKMOQ -> A0C0E0G0I0K0M0O0Q0
```

To get the logarithmic resolution in frequency, the low subband is
re-transformed, and again, the low subband from this transformation
gets the same treatment etc.

Decomposition:

```
    -> high -> decimate --------------------------------> subband0
   |   pass    by 2
in |                 -> high -> decimate ---------------> subband1
   |                |   pass    by 2
    -> low -> decim |                 -> high -> decim -> subband2
       pass   by 2  |                |   pass    by 2
                     -> low -> decim |
                        pass   by 2  |   .   down to what suffices
                                      -> .    or if periodic data,
                                         .     until short of data
```

Reconstruction:

```
subband0 -----------------------------------> dilute -> high
                                              by 2      pass \
subband1 ------------------> dilute -> high                   + out
                             by 2      pass \                /  =in
subband2 -> dilute -> high                   + dilute -> low
            by 2      pass \                /  by 2      pass
                            + dilute -> low
Start   .                  /  by 2      pass
here!   . -> dilute -> low
        .    by 2      pass
```

In a real-time application, the filters introduce delays, so you need
to compensate them by adding additional delays to less-delayed higher
bands, to get the summation work as intended.

For periodic signals or windowed operation, this problem doesn't exist -
a single subband transformation is a matrix multiplication, with wrapping
implemented in the matrix:

Decomposition:

```
|L0|   |C0  C1  C2  C3                | |I0|     L = lowpass output
|H0|   |C3 -C2  C1 -C0                | |I1|     H = highpass output
|L1|   |        C0  C1  C2  C3        | |I2|     I = input
|H1| = |        C3 -C2  C1 -C0        | |I3|     C = coefficients
|L2|   |                C0  C1  C2  C3| |I4|
|H2|   |                C3 -C2  C1 -C0| |I5|
|L3|   |C2  C3                  C0  C1| |I6|
|H3|   |C1 -C0                  C3 -C2| |I7|     Daubechies 4-coef:

     1+sqrt(3)        3+sqrt(3)        3-sqrt(3)        1-sqrt(3)
C0 = ---------   C1 = ---------   C2 = ---------   C3 = ---------
     4 sqrt(2)        4 sqrt(2)        4 sqrt(2)        4 sqrt(2)
```

Reconstruction:

```
|I0|   |C0  C3                  C2  C1| |L0|
|I1|   |C1 -C2                  C3 -C0| |H0|
|I2|   |C2  C1  C0  C3                | |L1|
|I3| = |C3 -C0  C1 -C2                | |H1|
|I4|   |        C2  C1  C0  C3        | |L2|
|I5|   |        C3 -C0  C1 -C2        | |H2|
|I6|   |                C2  C1  C0  C3| |L3|
|I7|   |                C3 -C0  C1 -C2| |H3|
```

C0, C1, C2, C3 are the "db2" lowpass FIR filter coefficients. Highpass
coefficients you get by reversing tap order and multiplying by
sequence 1,-1, 1,-1, ... Because these are orthogonal wavelets, the
analysis and reconstruction coefficients are the same.

A coefficient set convolved by its reverse is an ideal halfband lowpass
filter multiplied by a symmetric windowing function. This creates the
kind of symmetry in the frequency domain that enables aliasing-free
reconstruction. Daubechies wavelets are the minimum-phase, minimum
number of taps solutions for a number of vanishing moments (seven in
"db7" etc.), which determines their frequency selectivity.

I was asked to show the matrices for 6 coefficients, so here they are, made a bit larger for clarity but could be the same size as before too. Decomposition:

```
|L0|   |C0  C1  C2  C3  C4  C5                | |I0|     
|H0|   |C5 -C4  C3 -C2  C1 -C0                | |I1|     
|L1|   |        C0  C1  C2  C3  C4  C5        | |I2|     
|H1|   |        C5 -C4  C3 -C2  C1 -C0        | |I3|     
|L2| = |                C0  C1  C2  C3  C4  C5| |I4|
|H2|   |                C5 -C4  C3 -C2  C1 -C0| |I5|
|L3|   |C4  C5                  C0  C1  C2  C3| |I6|
|H3|   |C1 -C0                  C5 -C4  C3 -C2| |I7|
|L4|   |C2  C3  C4  C5                  C0  C1| |I8|
|H4|   |C3 -C2  C1 -C0                  C5 -C4| |I9|
```

Reconstruction:

```
|I0|   |C0  C5                  C4  C1  C2  C3| |L0|
|I1|   |C1 -C4                  C5 -C0  C3 -C2| |H0|
|I2|   |C2  C3  C0  C5                  C4  C1| |L1|
|I3|   |C3 -C2  C1 -C4                  C5 -C0| |H1|
|I4| = |C4  C1  C2  C3  C0  C5                | |L2|
|I5|   |C5 -C0  C3 -C2  C1 -C4                | |H2|
|I6|   |        C4  C1  C2  C3  C0  C5        | |L3|
|I7|   |        C5 -C0  C3 -C2  C1 -C4        | |H3|
|I8|   |                C4  C1  C2  C3  C0  C5| |L4|
|I9|   |                C5 -C0  C3 -C2  C1 -C4| |H4|
```

With:

```
C0 = 3.326705529500826159985115891390056300129233992450683597084705e-01
C1 = 8.068915093110925764944936040887134905192973949948236181650920e-01
C2 = 4.598775021184915700951519421476167208081101774314923066433867e-01
C3 = -1.350110200102545886963899066993744805622198452237811919756862e-01
C4 = -8.544127388202666169281916918177331153619763898808662976351748e-02
C5 = 3.522629188570953660274066471551002932775838791743161039893406e-02
```

More coefficient sets can be found [here](http://yehar.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2009/09/daub.h).

Comment: Thanks a lot sir, i understood about this decomposition and reconstruction, but i am unable to understand ,like if i write a code on this dwt, how will i decipher the frequency and time details. More clearly, i wanted to do like, i am giving 32 samples as input and my code should give the frequency,time content of the samples whose amplitude exceeds a specific threshold.

Comment: In the DWT results, the subband index of a sample tells the frequency, and its time index together with the subband index (which determines the sampling frequency of the subband) tells the time.

Comment: Sir, i have understood like, to decompose and reconstruct the signals, we should apply the matrix. i.e it is equivalent to filtering once. So, now i am thinking like i will do the filtering several times and get a lot of sub-bands i.e L0 H0 L1 H1 L2 H2 etc. i have those results in an array. (i haven't done reconstruction). Could you kindly tell me how to proceed so as to get the time and frequency detail from this. It will be a great help if i get this information.

Comment: You can think of applying the matrix as half-band filtering. So If you apply the matrix to data with a sampling period $f_s$, the resulting upper band has frequency content from $\frac{f_s}{4}$ to $\frac{f_s}{2}$, and the resulting lower band has frequency content from 0 Hz to $\frac{f_s}{4}$. Discarding every second sample will reduce the sampling frequency of both of these data to $\frac{f_s}{2}$, and will alias the frequencies in the highpass band so that they are "upside down". You would continue decomposition of the lower band. So you see, DWT gives you only very low frequency resolution.

Comment: Situation is like i am sampling a voltage signal at the rate of 500ksps. i am continuously monitoring it and if i find that a sample value has gone beyond some threshold, i will move the next (say) 1024 samples to a buffer and do a dwt on it and find the frequency and time at which those events, maybe several KHz events (if there) have occurred. Now is it possible to do this with dwt considering the frequency resolution problem you mentioned.

Comment: It depends on whether that frequency resolution is good enough for you. The estimate of the frequency could be off by ±33 %.

Comment: could you make what you meant by the terms subband index and time index a little more clear please. I really appreciate your patience.

Comment: Subband index: In the ASCII art after "Decomposition:", you see things like subband0, subband1, subband2. The number (0, 1 or 2) is the subband index. Time index: Each subband data is a sequence of samples, and the time index is the (integer) position in that sequence.

Comment: is it possible to decipher anything from the values of L0 H0 L1 H1 etc itself after decomposition ,like if the value is more or less .@olli niemitalo

Comment: L0, L1, L2, L3 are the lower subband sequence, and H0, H1, H2, H3 are the higher subband sequence. You can do things like envelope detection (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Envelope_detector) on those sequences.

Comment: This discussion helped me understand a lot of things.really grateful for that.

Comment: is it possible to show me the matrix with daubechies 6 coefficients

Comment: there might be some limitations on the number of samples to be processed as per the number of coefficients or are there none

Comment: I think the only limitation is that there should be at least 2 samples to process so that highpass and lowpass filtering and decimation make sense. If there are more coefficients than there are samples, the coefficients will overlap in the matrix (and would be summed in it, with the appropriate signs) but I think it would still work.

Comment: Great ascii art wavelet explanation

Comment: @olli niemitalo Simply multiplying the matrix to the samples wont give the necessary filtering,no; We have to do a convolution of signal with filter coefficients to get the correct output. am i right

Comment: Convolution can be written as matrix multiplication and multiplying by that matrix implements convolution as well as subband splitting and decimation.

Comment: @olli Niemitalo  if i use dwt to extract transient features, any idea as to how to obtain the peak of the transients

Comment: I'd go for a sliding root-mean-square envelope follower as a first guess.

Comment: the difference between fft and dwt is that dwt gives time information,right. But while doing dwt on the signal what time information are we specifically getting (other than the fact that we are using the index of the array for getting the info.)What interpretation can be made from detail coefficient contents and time.kindly help@Olli Niemitalo

Comment: @olliNiemitalo i meant like , suppose i take the fourth level detail of a signal by doing dwt, how can i relate the peak or main content in that detail level to the time instant

Comment: Try an inverse wavelet transform of an unit impulse in one of the bands. That way you can see how such a "peak" relates to the fully time-domain signal.

Comment: @OlliNiemitalo How to understand the dwt output in matlab. i am not able to understand the frequency detail in matlab. could you kindly explain with an example.

Comment: I have not done DWT in Matlab

Comment: @Olli Niemitalo: For getting detail and approx in each level we are applying filter(lpf and hpf) on the low pass output every time. But by doing the matrix operation, there we are getting each detail and approx by shifting coefficients by two and then multiplying with the real samples(i.e applying lpf and hpf on real samples every level).Can you help me in relating both representations.

Comment: The matrix implements filtering (both lpf and hpf) with wraparound (assuming a periodic signal) followed by decimation by two. Because of the decimation the shift is by two. With just filtering (=convolution) the shift would be by one.

Comment: i understood that shifting part but i wanted to know this-here the matrix is applied on the original sample set but according to the figure you have shown we are applying the filter on the low pass output each time.i am not able to relate that

Comment: Apply the matrix repeatedly to the lowpass output of the previous application of the matrix. The matrix does not describe the whole transform, only one step.

Comment: @OlliNiemitalo could you kindly explain how to implement the envelope detector code. How it can be used to detect zero crossing

Comment: Please ask everyone for help not just me, and explain where you're stuck.